# Wrong SQL is being generated with fluent nhibernate when tables has one-to-many relationship

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, oracle11g

I have two tables, one UserDetails and another UserRoles. I mapped them in the following way. With this insert operation went fine but when i try to get the list of roles from user object, an exception is throwing. What i identified is, the SQL generated by Hibernate has USERCODE column as User_id in whare clause. How to over come this problem. Please help me.

User Class:

```
public virtual string Code { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual string MiddleName { get; set; }
    .......
    public virtual IList<UserRole> Roles { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<UserResource> Resources { get; set; }
```

User Map:

```
 Table("USER_DETAILS");
        Schema("PROJECTDOCS");
        Id(x => x.Code).Column("CODE").GeneratedBy.Assigned();
        Map(x => x.FirstName).Column("FIRSTNAME").Not.Nullable().Length(100);
        Map(x => x.LastName).Column("LASTNAME").Length(100).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.MiddleName).Column("MIDDLENAME").Length(100);
        ...
        HasMany(x => x.Roles).Inverse().Cascade.All();
```

UserRole Class:

```
 public virtual long UserRoleID { get; set; }
    public virtual User UserCode { get; set; }
    public virtual long RoleID { get; set; }
    public virtual string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
```

UserRole Map:

```
Table("USER_ROLES");
        Schema("PROJECTDOCS");
        Id(x => x.UserRoleID).Column("URID").GeneratedBy.Increment();
        Map(x => x.RoleID).Column("ROLEID").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.CreatedBy).Column("CREATEDBY").Not.Nullable().Length(36);
        Map(x => x.CreatedDate).Column("CREATEDDATE").Not.Nullable().Default(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        Map(x => x.UpdatedBy).Column("UPDATEDBY").Not.Nullable().Length(36);
        Map(x => x.UpdatedDate).Column("UPDATEDDATE").Not.Nullable().Default(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        References(x => x.UserCode).Column("USERCODE");
```

The final SQL generated was:

> [SQL: SELECT roles0_.User_id as User8_1_, roles0_.URID as URID1_, roles0_.URID as URID2_0_, roles0_.ROLEID as ROLEID2_0_, roles0_.CREATEDBY as CREATEDBY2_0_, roles0_.CREATEDDATE as CREATEDD4_2_0_, roles0_.UPDATEDBY as UPDATEDBY2_0_, 
>   roles0_.UPDATEDDATE as UPDATEDD6_2_0_, roles0_.USERCODE as USERCODE2_0_ FROM PROJECTDOCS.USER_ROLES roles0_ WHERE **roles0_.User_id**=?]

The bolded column name is what going worng.

Thanks in advance,
Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the key column on your HasMany to UserRoles in your UserClass.  You need to probably do this:

```
HasMany(x => x.Roles).KeyColumn("URID").Inverse().Cascade.All();
```